# Two genitives in serie with 's

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say : "What is the John's car's color ?" ?
As non native speaker, this sentence seems weird to me.
Would I say : "What is the color of the John's car ?"

Comment: Either is acceptable, except that a noun modified by a morphological genitive (*'s*) does not take an article, because the genitive  'fills up' the determiner 'slot': "What is John's car's color?", "What is the color of John's car?"